# How to set filter header in Undertow without Wildfly

Tags: java, filter, header, wildfly, undertow

I'm just started with Undertow.
I would like to add the header filter that only allows the request with RequestProperty like below code.

```
con.setRequestProperty("X-Client-Token", TOKEN);
con.setRequestProperty("X-Client-Secret", SECRET);
```

I have been written the method to check the header after receiving the request by using `HttpServerExchange exchange` after implement `io.undertow.server.HttpHandler`. But I need to use this method for each request after receiving.

So. It's there any other way to check and filter the header parameters in undertow without using Wildfly server. And how to do it.

Thank you.